# Windows Active Directory - adding specific A Host

Tags: active-directory, records, hosts

I'm currently working on my active directory. I have a few A records (hosts) already. **For example: in our network we have an exchange server. To surf to this exchange server we enter "www.mailbox.domain.com/exchange" in our webbrowser.** 
But what we want to do is be able to only enter www.mailbox.domain.com and land on the www.mailbox.domain.com/exchange page.

You can't alter this in the host records since you can **only add text in front of the domainname not behind it.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Enable http redirection in IIS on your CAS/Front end servers to forward you from www.mailbox.domain.com to www.mailbox.domain.com/exchange